# Why is private variable of another class accessible inside .Equals override?

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private int TestVariable;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        TestClass testClass = obj as TestClass;
        return TestVariable == testClass.TestVariable;
    }
}
```

How does this line compile:

```
return TestVariable == testClass.TestVariable;
```

`TestVariable` is private and is being accessed externally. If I change the line to this then it does not compile as I would expect:

```
return TestVariable == obj.TestVariable;
```

Comment: But - when you're calling obj.TestVariable it would fail because its private and effectively you are external to it - you arent using "this" but a new version of the class you're in you cant see that.. I have a brain (apparently) so do you, you can ask me whats in my brain and I can tell you but you cant read it yourself, whereas you can read your own but we both came from template human (I hope)

Comment: private means (from docs): "The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.". Your code is in the same class, so it can access it.

Comment: I don't know C#, but it doesn't look like it's being accessed from another class. Looks like a private variable being accessed within the class that owns it, which is completely fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different things here:

```
obj.TestVariable
```

This does not work because the type of `obj` is `object` and instances of the type `object` do not have a `TestVariable` member. So accessing it will not work.

```
testClass.TestVariable
```

This however will work because `testClass` is of the same type as the type you are currently in. That way, you are *within* the private scope of that type, so you can access private variables, even if the object you are referring to is not the same object as `this`.

See also the [language documentation on the `private` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private) (emphasis mine):

> Private members are accessible only **within the body of the class** or the struct in which they are declared […]
>
> Nested types in the same body can also access those private members.

So since you are still *within the body of the class*, you can access the member. As the following paragraph explains, this even works from within *nested* types although the nested type is a completely different type that has no required type relationship to its parent. But it works since the nested type definition is *within* the body of its parent type.

Comment: Thanks, so if I create ten TestClass instances inside TestClass, then I can create the private variables of eleven TestClass instances inside the TestClass that creates them? +1.

Comment: Yes, if you create a `TestClass` object within the instance method of another `TestClass` instance, you can still access that new instance’s private members.

Answer (score 4):

Accessibility is not about instances but types

Why: because you are in the class `TestClass` and can access every private member in that class, even if you are not referring to `this` but an instance that you get there. That's by-design.

The C# lang specs mention it under 3.5.2:
....

> Otherwise, **if M is private, the access is permitted if it occurs
>   within the type in which M is declared.** ...

So if a member is private you can access it within the same type not only the same instance.

Side-note: if it wasn't implemented in this way it would be impossible to provide a copy constructor that takes another instance to initialize this, because some properties might be inaccessible.

Comment: But I am referring to another instance of TestClass?

Comment: @w0051977: accessibbility is not about instances but types

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the meaning of `private`. `private` does not mean that you can only access that member with `this.`. It means that you can only access that member within that class.

The `Equals` method is inside `TestClass`, so `TestVariable` is accessible. It does not matter which object's `TestVariable` that you are accessing.

Why design it like this?

The whole point of `private` is not to limit access to one instance, but to limit access to the implementation. When you declare something as `private`, you don't want other code (which might be written by someone else who does not know the implementation details) to mess around with implementation-detail members because it might mess stuff up.